# Create new task on Azure Boards using Azure API

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

We have our board set up and want to open a new task using the Azure API, so far I created an basic task using the following documentation: [Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0).

[image: Sample Task]

Using the following body:

```json
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "from": None,
    "value": "Sample task"
  }
]
```

But now I want to actually put the 'Sample task' inside an iteration (Sprint), but for some reason I can't find a way to pull that off.

I've tried the following way:

```json
body = 
[
   { 
     "op": "add", 
     "path": "/fields/System.Title", 
     "from": None, 
     "value": "Sample task",  
     "op": "add", 
     "path": "/fields/System.IterationPath",
     "from": None,
     "value": "Labs_TelAviv\Sprint32"
   }
]
```

```json
[
    { 
      "op": "add",
      "path": "/fields/System.Title",
      "path": "/fields/System.IterationPath",
      "from": None,
      "value": "Sample task",
    }
]
```

Microsoft documentation doesn't specify which custom/basic fields that we can configure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this template:

```
body = 
[
   { 
     "op": "add", 
     "path": "/fields/System.Title", 
     "from": None, 
     "value": "Sample task"
   },
   {
     "op": "add", 
     "path": "/fields/System.IterationPath",
     "from": None,
     "value": "Labs_TelAviv\Sprint32"
   }
]
```

Check examples about update operation, it contains several fields: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#examples

Comment: Thank you very very much was searching for few hours now.